# Java Double Ternary Null Pointer

Tags: java, ternary

This produces null pointer:

```
boolean treatNullAsFalse = false;
String what = null;
System.out.println(what == null ? (treatNullAsFalse ? false : null) :  what.equals("1")); // NULL POINTER
```

This doesn't.

```
boolean treatNullAsFalse = false;
String what = null;
System.out.println(what == null ? (treatNullAsFalse ? false : null) :  (Boolean)what.equals("1"));
```

**Any help, why does the (Boolean) cast fix the issue?** I thought ternary operators figure out return types at compile time, but here some unboxing is producing an NPE.

Comment: Unrelated: in my opinion, using nested ternaries makes for very hard to read code, and is best avoided.

Comment: If you apply the equals() method to a null String, it'll raise the exception. Try it outside the complicated ternary stuff and you'll be able to see it.

Comment: @Alfabravo, it should never evaluate the right side expression if `what` is null. It knows the types at compile time.

Comment: What JVM/JDK version?

Comment: who down-vote this good question?!!!!!

Comment: This has nothing to do with ternaries but rather with `System.out.println` method. If you cast your `null` as a `String` or a char, your code will work: `System.out.println(what == null ? (treatNullAsFalse ? false : (String) null) :  what.equals("1"));`

Comment: Thanks mods for closing my question. To anyone who needs an actual answer, read this: second and third arguments need to be the same type. If one of the types is primitive, the other one has to be too. When it tries to unbox null (at runtime), it causes an NPE. Types are known at compile time, but not the ones that would avoid an NPE (boolean vs Boolean).

Comment: @barti_ddu it has nothing to do with System.out.println(). Try this: `Boolean b = (what == null ? (treatNullAsFalse ? false : null) :  what.equals("1"))`

Comment: Good one, I assumed, that this was the same as with `System.out.println(null)`.